# Back wheel lock up, when got off wheel would move side to side

Tags: mountain-bike, repair, hub, freewheel, bearings

I have a 29 inch Iron-Horse/Sunday 24 speed. My back wheel locked up, when I got off the wheel would move side to side.

I thought I lost bearings, took my freewheel apart and clean. Doesn't look like I lost any bearings, but not sure.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Bicycles Stack Exchange! It is really unclear what are the symptoms you describe, what measures you took and finally, what question you meant to ask. Please improve your question with more detailed and thorough description; you are very welcome to add pictures that illustrate what you see. Otherwise it will be very hard to help you.

Comment: "side to side" sounds like the bearing cup/cones are maladjusted.   Not sure how lockup relates, nor the freewheel.  What's the question ?

Answer (score 1):

If the wheel wobbles in the frame (and the QR or through axle is tight), or with the wheel out you can wobble the axle in the hub: at least one of the bearings has a problem, or perhaps the axle broke or the hub shell has failed. If you have a serviceable cup and cone bearing hub, one of the cones may simply have come loose.

The way forward depends on what kind of hub you have. Without more info on the specifics of you hub we can't provide further advice.